# Fetch Users Logged-in information in Linux using LKM

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel-module

I am writing an LKM (loadable kernel Module) in C, I want to fetch information about users logged in currently and who is going to logout and login while LKM loaded.

Problem is LKM uses only system calls not library calls.
I have read **utmp.h**  it uses library calls but LKM need system calls for this purpose.
I have also used **strace who** but I didn't get solution.

Comment: The linux kernel doesn't really know and/or support the concept of logged-in users, this is all done purely in userspace. You could however find out if and how many processes associated with a certain userid are running

Comment: That does not make sense to me. Do it in user space, let your kernel module provide an interface and your user space code communicates the results to your kernel module.

Comment: @AdrianW how can I  provide  interface to user space program in kernel module?

Comment: One possibility is to create [sysfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt) entries. That allows user space code to talk to your kernel module. There are [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10816801/2311167) too,

Comment: **/var/log/wtmp** or **/var/run/utmp** files  carry  about  logged  users but  these are  binary  files.
which  struct is used to read  these files.