# Implementing Linux System Call using LKM

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel-module

I was trying to add a new System Call to linux kernel 3.2.x.
While searching for useful reference material over the internet i had an impression that implementing system call as a loadable module is not possible as in SO question [Is it possible to add a system call via a LKM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463332/is-it-possible-to-add-a-system-call-via-a-lkm)

I found another link which says this "There is a way to add system calls without recompiling the kernel using modules as a wrapper, but that is beyond the scope of this document".
source http://hekimian-williams.com/?p=20

I know implementing system call statically will require me to compile the kernel code each time i make any changes. Is there a way as specified in the above mentioned blog that i can implement it as a module.

Any suggestions or pointers in the direction are much appreciated.

Comment: Can you solve your problem using a device driver model instead?  With an open character device you can use read(), write(), ioctl(), etc. to  communicate from userspace to kernel space.  The result would be much more portable.

Comment: @Peter yes it can be done by i was looking for this solution specifically as i am trying to learn this. Do you have any idea what this guy in the blog is talking.. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Locate `sys_call_table/ia32_sys_call_table`
2. Make a copy and modify it as you wish (let it be `my_sys_call_table`)
3. Locate [system_call](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.5.4/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S#L489) entry (this one and others)
4. Modify `NR_syscalls` compare [instruction](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.5.4/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S#L497) in case of table size has changed
5. Modify `sys_call_table` reference at [system_call](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.5.4/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S#L500) to point to `my_sys_call_table`:

   ```
   500        call *sys_call_table(,%eax,4)
         ->
   500        call *my_sys_call_table(,%eax,4)
   ```
6. Profit?

Have fun :)

Comment: @llya thanks for the reply.. i will try to implement your suggestion. Though in the point 6 what do you mean by Profit?.. thanks

Comment: @abhi: Note that `system_call` is in `.text` segment and is RO. You'll need to find a way to write to read-only kernel's memory. Also, note that the write must be atomic operation in case of SMP-systems. `Profit?` means that from the 6th step you'll get the profit :)